# Paperclip exception : Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Using Paperclip 3.0.1 in rails 3.2.2 I got this error:

```
**Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError** 
(No handler found for "2009-11-29-133527.jpg"):
```

In my model I have:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :assets 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
 end

 class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :product
     has_attached_file :image,
               :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
               :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
               :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  end
```

The exception is raised at:

```
def create
     **@product = Product.new params[:product]**
     ...
end
```

with params:

```
{...,
 "product"=>{"title"=>"wibble1", 
             **"assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>"2009-11-29-133527.jpg"}
                                  },** 
             "description"=>"Who is wibble...", 
             "price"=>"23.45"
            }, 
             "commit"=>"Create Product", 
             ...}
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 50):

This Error is raised because you aren't giving Paperclip a correct class. It's a just a String.

You should receive something like this in `params`

```
"asset"=>
  {"image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000056679e8
    @content_type="image/jpg",
    @headers= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[image]\";
      filename=\"2009-11-29-133527.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n",
    @original_filename=""2009-11-29-133527.jpg"",
    @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120619-1043-yvc9ox>>}
```

And you should have something like this in yout View (in HAML, very simplified):

```
= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.fields_for :asset do |asset_form|
    = asset_form.file_field :image
```

Remember to set your form to `multipart: true`.

Comment: Yes do remember to set the multipart option. 
For example : <%= form_for @video, :method => :put, :html => { :multipart => true} do %>

Comment: In case of form_tag it should be `form_tag path, :multipart => true` without :html key. [Link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/865)

Comment: What in case I am selecting image from assets.

Comment: @Imran How are you selecting it? It sounds like a different question really

Answer (score 30):

I just ran into this problem myself.  In my case it was caused by skipping the multipart form declaration in the markup.

I was using formtastic so I added this and got it working:

`semantic_form_for @picture, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|`

Comment: For future googlers, if you're using form_for and adding fields outside of the builder, you have to manually force form_for to be multipart, via `:html => {:multipart => true}` as shown above. Simply adding `:multipart => true` doesn't work like it does with form_tag

Comment: This answer worked for me! I hope the asker would accept this one. This is usually the case that happens when you create a form for a model, then eventually have nested attributes for sub objects that accepts files as attachments which, in my case, was the scenario. (relating my story here for future googlers)

Answer (score 5):

Note there is a situation when working with an HTML5 canvas that is worth noting.  Getting the canvas data as a DataURI string and sending that to server can cause this error.  Canvas .toDataURL() will give something like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." which you can send to server with other information, so its different than a standard multi-part form upload.  On the server side if you just set this to the paperclip attachment field you will get this error.  You need to conver it to a file or IO object.  You could write a temp file like this:

```
data_uri = params[:canvasDataUri]
encoded_image = data_uri.split(",")[1]
decoded_image = Base64.decode64(encoded_image)
File.open("signature.png", "wb") { |f| f.write(decoded_image) }
```

or use Ruby's StringIO which acts like an in memory file interface

```
@docHolder.document = StringIO.new(decoded_image)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had `<input type="file" ... multiple="multiple">` on file input, so paperclip attachment data was in an array.
I solved this simply by removing multiple attribute on file input.

Comment: This was my problem, as well. I liked the convenience of `:multiple => true`, but as you say, it sets the name as `upload[upload][]`. However, I really like the convenience of multiple file selection, so I just set the name manually to not be an array with `:name => 'upload[upload]'`.

Comment: I add multiple with javascript together with jquery fileupload ;)

Comment: Hah!  Almost three years later, and I ran into exactly this on another project, and as before, this answer and my comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

my problem was not accepting get method in routes so i changed it as patch method and it work fine.

```
<%= form_for @product, :url => "/products/#{@product.id}/upload",:method => :patch, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is with the form_for in the view,
try something like this:

```
<%= form_for @restaurante, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
   Nome:<%= form.text_field :nome%>
   Endereço:<%= form.text_field :endereco %>
   Especialidade:<%= form.text_field :especialidade %>
   Foto:<%= form.file_field :foto %>
   <%= form.submit 'create'%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was passing String, as in @MauricioPasquierJuan's answer, but I wasn't using a form so the rest of the answer doesn't apply.

I couldn't find any documentation of how to programatically update an attachment - what types can be assigned, and why assigning and saving the modified record does not save modified attachments.  This question was the closest thing I found.

Inside a function that process files inside an uploaded zip file, after saving extracted files to temp files, this is my solution:

```
record.attachment = File.new( tempfile_path_as_string ) ## probably not the only option
record.attachment.save                                  ## next line doesn't update attachment without this
record.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you migrate the database after you install Paperclip ('rake db:migrate')... Also, you might need to add the new data fields generated by Paperclip to your  'attr_accessible'  line in the model.
I had a similar problem when I was trying to get Paperclip workin on one of my projects.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem for me. Same problem adding attr_accessible  :title,:description,:price,:assets_attributes,

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, I think it is because there are two tables sharing the same `attached_file_name`... In my case, I add a `:photo` column both to activities and tweets, then the case seems to be that the system can find one of them but not the other. Because the files are saved in `/public/photo/:id/:id` path, if you have two columns both named as `photo`, then the problem occurs I think.

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was like this:

I used such line in controller, as saw it in some answers:

```
@image = User.find(params[:id]).image.<b>path</b>(:small)
```

and I had the problem "no handler for the file"

so, I just removed "path" and it worked:

```
@image = User.find(params[:id]).image(:small)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we upgraded from 4.2.x to 4.3.x, we had to change the main paperclip field attribute (`picture`, `image`, etc) from a relative URL to a full URL to eliminate this error.