# Paperclip::Attachment passed as string when using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, paperclip, factory-bot

I am trying to create a functional test for paperclip 3.1.2 on rails 3.2.6 using FactoryGirl 3.0 and when i pass the file attachment my controller receives a string which is the file location and not the Paperclip::Attachment object.

My factory is:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :artist do
    id 1
    name 'MyString'
    photo {fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/rails.png",'image/png')}
  end
end
```

And my test is:

```
test "should create artist" do
  assert_difference('Artist.count') do
    post :create, :artist => { name: @artist.name, photo: @artist.photo }, :html => { :multipart => true }
  end

  assert_redirected_to artist_path(assigns(:artist))
end
```

In my controller this :

```
params[:artist][:photo].class.name
```

equals "String", but this passes when i add it to the test

```
assert @artist.photo.class.name == "Paperclip::Attachment"
```

My current workaround is to create the fixture_file_upload in the test :

```
test "should create artist" do
  assert_difference('Artist.count') do
    photo = fixture_file_upload("/files/rails.png",'image/png')
    post :create, :artist => { name: @artist.name, photo: photo }, :html => { :multipart => true }
  end

  assert_redirected_to artist_path(assigns(:artist))
end
```

which works but creates a "Rack::Test::UploadedFile" and so I'm pretty confused why my factory returns a "Paperclip::Attachment" when the same method is called to create them both.

Thanks in advance for any light that you can shed on this as obviously I would like to use the factory rather than defining the fixture_file_upload outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace

```
photo {fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/rails.png",'image/png')}
```

with

```
photo File.new("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/rails.png")
```

inside your factory.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same result