# NoHandlerError with Rails3 and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

So this is my first question on StackOverflow.

I'm trying to implement Paperclip on Rails 3.2.3, and after clicking "submit" to create a profile with an uploaded image, I get:

> Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in UsersController#update
>
> No handler found for "Screen Shot 2012-09-01 at 11.03.43 AM.png"

My server log reads,

> Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "Screen Shot 2012-09-01 at 11.03.43 AM.png"):
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:65:in `block in update'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in`update'

In my User model, I have

```
attr_accessible :avatar

has_attached_file :avatar, 
        :styles => { 
          :large => "500x500>", 
          :medium => "213x213>", # profile image
          :thumb => "50x50>",
          :smaller => "30x30>" }, 
          :processors => [:cropper],
         # tells paperclip how to crop the image  
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", # TODO 
        :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
        :bucket => 'eventsbucket'
```

The error persists whether I include the S3 info or not. In my migration I have,

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Lastly, in my Users controller update action, I have

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        sign_in @user
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile Successfully Updated' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end
```

In my Gemfile I have gem "paperclip", "~> 3.1.4" (UPDATE: I've since pulled Paperclip straight from thoughtbot and problem persists). I've run bundle install. I've run db:migrate. I've read [this StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033425/paperclip-exception-paperclipadapterregistrynohandlererror), but the error persists whether I include "multipart => true" or not. When I tried the [Emerson Lackey Tutorial](http://emersonlackey.com/screencasts/rails-3-with-paperclip.mov), it worked up to the point where he tried to display the output of the "5.times..." command.

I'm interested in both getting Paperclip to work and understanding just what a "NoHandlerError" is and how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033425/paperclip-exception-paperclipadapterregistrynohandlererror

Comment: Looks promising, when I get some time I will check further into that just for curiosity sake. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you  try the railscasts episode # 134 ?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?view=asciicast