# Getting Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError when using Padrino

Tags: paperclip, padrino

I've been getting an issue where when using Padrino and paperclip whenever I try to upload an image I get the error

`Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError`

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, the multipart form thing mentioned in many other posts is also true. See [Other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033425/paperclip-exception-paperclipadapterregistrynohandlererror)

All of those relate to Rails and specifically if you are using Padrino or another rack based application, you need to add one more thing or else it won't work

The exception being thrown was due to the uploaded file being represented by a Hash (Rack converts it into a Hash), and that Paperclip does not provide an adapter for this Rack specific Hash out of the box.

You need to install this gem:

`gem 'paperclip-rack', require: 'paperclip/rack'`