# Rails 5 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I cannot figure out where I went wrong. My form is written different then most people with the same issue so I have not been able to configure it properly. I tried to submit my form with an attachment and I got the following error:

[image: error]

Here is my controller:

```
class CareersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @career = Career.new

  end
  def show
    @career = Career.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def create
    # fail
    @career = Career.create(career_params)
    if @career.save
      CareerMailer.career_inquiry(@career).deliver
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
      flash[:error] = @career.errors.full_messages
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end


  end
  private
  def career_params
    params.require(:career).permit(:name, :phone, :subject, :email, :message, :document)
  end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Career < ApplicationRecord

    has_attached_file :document

    validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 25.megabytes    
    validates_attachment_presence :document
     validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ["application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
                                                                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                                                                    "application/msword", 
                                                                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
                                                                    "text/plain"]

    email_regex = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :subject, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :phone, :presence => true,
    :length          => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true,
              :format          => {:with => email_regex }
    validates :message, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 5000 }

end
```

Here is my actual form:

```
 <form  class="margin-clear" role="form" method="post" action="careers#create" >
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%=form_authenticity_token%>">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="name">Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="career[name]" placeholder="">
    <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="email">Email*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="career[email]" placeholder="">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number*</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="career[phone]" placeholder="">
    <i class="fa fa-phone form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="subject">Subject*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="career[subject]" placeholder="">
    <i class="fa fa-navicon form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="subject">Upload Resume*</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="career[document]" placeholder="">
    <i class="fa fa-file form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="message">Message*</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="message" name="career[message]" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div> -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button btn btn-default">
</form>
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to attach a resume in a variety of formats such as pdf, word, et cetera and have it sent to the database. I am using paperclip gem for rails.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033425/paperclip-exception-paperclipadapterregistrynohandlererror

Comment: I've seen that one I am having a difficulty translating the haml into my version. This is why I asked my question.

Comment: try adding `enctype` property in your form tag like this `<form  class="margin-clear" role="form" method="post" action="careers#create"  enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: That one line worked like a charm thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `multipart/form-data` property in your form tag. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

```
<form class="margin-clear" role="form" method="post" action="careers#create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Once again thank you for your help. The other methods would have required me to convert my whole form so you are a life saver.